# Flask session persists locally, but not on Heroku server

Tags: python, flask

I have made my first flask app and deployed it on [Heroku](https://plex-web.herokuapp.com/connect).

However, the session doesn't work on the Heroku server. It keeps resetting and sometimes I'm connected, sometimes not. It's a pain to use it on there. However, locally it works great. No problems at all.

Link to my [repo](https://github.com/banjoanton/plex-web).

This is the setup for my sessions (based on CS50):

```
# use filesystem instead of cookies for sessions
app.config["SESSION_FILE_DIR"] =  mkdtemp()
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)
```

Comment: if you're using the filesystem for your sessions (and I'm not sure why you would), then [this](https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted) is the reason

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I just went with what I knew, do you have any alternative suggestion I could use?

Comment: Can't you just use more normal cookie-based sessions? If for some reason you have to use the filesystem, then you'll need to host it on a server with a real filesystem, and not Heroku.

Comment: Ok - I'll change to that. I learnt that this was the safer way to store sensitive information. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this arrives a bit too late, But I had the same issue and the same setup (Using server-side sessions in flask and avoiding cookie storage to mitigate risk for session hijacking). And noticed this behavior when deploying to Apache with wsgi.

This happens due to to cache policy, (I noticed that refreshing the webpage initialized the session). What worked for me was to set headers in .conf file for that virtualhost with the following settings:

```
Header set Cache-Control "public, max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "0"
```

After that, sessions worked properly as they did locally.

Hope someone find this useful. ✌